# Google Drive on Mac disk uses 11 GB

Tags: macos, google-apps

I have an iMac running High Sierra. Years ago I signed up for Google Drive and currently have about 70 GB free space remaining out of my 100 GB subscription.

I have a Google Drive folder on my internal main drive. This folder has 11 GB of files on it. The folder is located at the top level given by /. What is this local Google Drive and why is it taking up 11 GB on my nearly full SSD.

Comment: **1** So the folder is `/Google Drive` ? I use OneDrive and it asked me where to put the folder. `/Users/me/OneDrive` it is.  **2** Did you reboot to see if it clears up? **3** Would a delete and re-install cost a lot of bandwidth?

Comment: yes, /Google Drive is the location.  I have restarted several times and in Safe Mode several times.  I guess I can copy those files to my external drive and try deleting them all and seeing what happens.

Comment: Check with google forums once, if you haven’t deleted anything yet